# How to resolve this npm install error? Should I update node-sass or is pyton the problem?

Tags: reactjs, node-sass

I can't do "npm install" on this project anymore and I don't know why because I'm a novice.
I see in the picture top that something about "node-sass" maybe is the problem. Should I update node-sass? I must ask so I don't cause more trouble

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "greta-thunberg-fff",
  "version": "1.2.9",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://greta.portplays.com",
  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "clean-tag": "^3.1.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "comma-separated-values": "^3.6.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "firebase": "^7.23.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.5",
    "framer-motion": "^2.9.5",
    "gsap": "^3.5.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "mammoth": "^1.4.11",
    "material-table": "^1.69.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "normalize-wheel": "^1.0.1",
    "notistack": "^1.0.10",
    "npm": "^7.11.2",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^1.8.357",
    "preval.macro": "^5.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-activity": "^1.2.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-data-grid": "^6.1.0",
    "react-detect-offline": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.4",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-resize-detector": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.3",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "rebass": "^4.0.7",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "three": "^0.85.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.10.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=6545&& react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "clean-tag": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.2",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "rebass": "^4.0.7",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: `node-sass` is no longer maintained. Switch to the `sass` package.

Comment: @AKX In VSCode I search for node-sass, seems like I did not use it in any ReactJs files. Do you think it's safe to remove from package.json.

Comment: Well, surely you have your project in version control? You can try it, build it, see if it works, and if it doesn't, revert to a working version.

Comment: @AKX, what is that , "Switch to the sass package". can you be precise please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node-sass 4.x doesn't support Node 16 https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy (I believe this might also be the case for CRA)

Comment: Thanks yea I have Node v16.9.1. What du you suggest to migrate all scss files to?

Comment: I'd probably suggest sticking to Node 14, which is the current long term support release for Node.js

Comment: I just did "npm i sass" and that fixed the problem. I did nothing more the `sass` took care of all scss files